# MySQL error 'with base as' subqueries and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I don't know why the company it is using such an old version of MySQL, but it is: 5.6.

We have some duplicate subdomains. For instance, given a subdomain of `fastelvis` we get 6 results, but there should only be one, the one that has lowest ID of the 6. This query works correctly and shows me the duplicate subdomains:

```
select subdomain, ID 
from clients where subdomain in 
    (select subdomain 
    from clients 
    group by subdomain 
    having count(*) > 1 ) 
order by subdomain, FSID ;
```

That works great.

The ID is an integer field, auto-incrementing.

But I need to find the lowest ID of any set of duplicates. That is, if `fastelvis` has IDs of 11, 27, 94, 149, 2398, and 9322, then I need to find just `11`.

I thought this would get me what I want:

```
With base as (
select subdomain,
       ID
from clients
where subdomain in 
    (select subdomain 
    from clients 
    group by subdomain 
    having count(*) > 1 )
order by subdomain, ID)
SELECT subdomain,
       MIN(ID) first_subdomain_ID
FROM base
GROUP BY subdomain
```

I've been looking at this for 20 minutes and I don't see any syntax errors, but I get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'base as ( select subdomain,
```

I'm left wondering, maybe this syntax doesn't work in this version of MySQL?

Does anyone see a syntax error?

Comment: The [common table expression syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) was introduced in MySQL 8.0, which was generally available (i.e. not in beta) as of 2018.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it was a version issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select subdomain,
       MIN(id) AS min_id
    from clients 
    group by subdomain 
    having count(*) > 1
```